# put a new element in arrayList not in its head

Tags: java, multithreading, list, arraylist

I have this code:

however when I try to add

```
completeRoutingResponses = new ArrayList<>(8); //doesn't this mean there are 8 places in the list which I can put data into?

completeRoutingResponses.add(3, routingResponse1);

completeRoutingResponses.add(2, routingResponse2);

completeRoutingResponses.add(5, routingResponse3);

completeRoutingResponses.add(0, routingResponse4);
```

the list size doesn't change and the item is not added,

but only when I add to the next head position (by order).

Is there a way to do this? (like putting into an array at position `i`, but I still want to use `ArrayList`)

I'm actually using multi-threaded code

but it doesn't matter for the sick of the question because I see in debug mode the `add` is called 8 times, but eventually the list has only 2 items.

Comment: This code will throw an exception as-is. http://ideone.com/b0BIdv Please show us the [minimal but complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behavior you are seeing and more clearly explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Post your real code. ("add is called 8 times" but in your sample it's only 4 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new ArrayList<>(8);

only means that the list has initial capacity of 8, so that before you add 8 elements it will not need to resize its internal buffer.

It does not create "empty" slots in the list, it is not an array.

List stores only real elements.

You can manaully add 8 nulls to the list and then call set(ix,element) to place the items in the right place. But you need to add the null first otherwise you will get exception as you will be setting elements outside the current list content.

Also your current code, should never complete as you would get the exception after the first add(3, routingResponse1) as it would be outside the list content. You mentioned multi threading so you might just got lucky with that.

Comment: thanks. I never get an exception. I don't understand why. ran the code few times.